# name for quasi-modulo function

Tags: while-loop, range, modulo, bounds, clip

Is there a name for this function? It is like modulo with elastic boundaries. Here's an example of modulo 10 but with a 'grace' of 3 on either end:

```
while n < -3
  n += 10;
while n => 13
  n -= 10;
return n;
```

I need it often but don't know what to call it.

Comment: Modulo would be: if n < 0 then add 10, if n => 10 then subtract 10.

Comment: I meant the name of the function. Why not call id modulo? Make the -3 and 13 boundaries as parameter and the name is well chosen.

Comment: Alright, maybe just modBounded or modGrace. If it's not already known as something, or if this is indeed modulo with extra params. (I understand there are various definitions of modulo, esp. re. negative numbers.) Thanks for the support!